# VUE how to replace json variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have defined in `data()` JSON and url variable:

```
data() {
return {
  url: '',
  startsession: {
    cmd: 'start',
    width: 1024,
    height: 800,
    url: 'https://www.test.com',
    token: '',
    service_id: 1,
    thumbnail_width: 100,
    thumbnail_height: 100,
  },
```

url is assigned to input:

```
<b-form-input v-model="url" />
```

I also have button:

```
<b-button
    @click="sendMessage(startsession)"
  >
```

Could you please help me, how to replace 'url' param in JSON with url variable from input, that when i click button, the 'sesstionstart' JSON will have value from input?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of methods. First, define a method with name sendMessage and then just access the variables using `this` and update the startsession.url with url.

```
methods: {
    sendMessage () {
        this.startsession.url = this.url
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **b-form-input** component has syntax like this :
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

in base, you will pass url as prop to **b-form-input**, and in this child component, you need emit a event to tell parent the value of url is changed. Then, just use sendMessage method like @Yash